# FragmentTabHost not following generated tabstyle?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-tabhost

I've generated a custom style for my application based on http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator.

However when i try to integrate into my application, the style is not working for the fragmenttabhost of one of my page. The rest of the style is working fine for my actionbar and etc.

The following is my fragmenttabhost

```
 public final class DashBoardFragmentTabHost extends SherlockFragment  {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
    public DashBoardFragmentTabHost()
    {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    try{

        mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getSherlockActivity());
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.fragment_tabhost);
            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("abc").setIndicator("abc"),
                abc.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("def").setIndicator("def"),
                def.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("ghi").setIndicator("ghi"),
                ghi.class, null);



        //mTabHost.set (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_indicator_ab_safetyblue));



    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
        return mTabHost;


    }



}
```

fragment_tabs.xml

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: It's not clear how do you apply those styles. That generator styles the tabs of the `ActionBar`, but you're using a `FragmentTabHost` which wraps a simple `TabHost`(along with its components) which will not be affected by the styles for the `ActionBar` tabs. Instead, you need to override the `tabWidgetStyle` attribute in the current theme(which, by default, points to the `Widget.TabWidget` style).

Comment: Please can you just provide a sample way?